# How to format a string without converting to right type

Tags: c#, formatting

is it possible to format a string without convrting it to the specific type?

Let's say I have a string '22.5' and a format 'C2', or a string '1/30/2020 7:50:28 AM' and a format 't'.

Is it anyhow possible to create a formated string without converting the strings with the values to their data types?

Something like :

```
String.Format("{0:t}", "1/30/2020 7:50:28 AM");
```

Comment: It is not. How would .NET understand what the object is intended to be?

Comment: basically on the format string, I mean 't' stands for a DateTime format

Comment: You could make your own extension method for `string`, but I am pretty sure there are no built in features for this.

Comment: The only way to do it would be to parse it yourself, e.g. `"1/30/2020 7:50:28 AM".Split(' ')[1]`. But that means you're also in charge of validation (and potentially globalization), which is pretty involved. It's easier to validate by converting to a `DateTime` first then back to a string.

Comment: Doing it in an extension way would work, I mean DateTime.Parse("8/18") gives a dateTime '8/18/2020 12:00:00 AM'. I see I will have to create an Extension, but I thought there were build in methods.

Comment: Re-adding my comment with an edit (sorry): How would it know how to parse the date? What if you're in the US but have a dd/MM/yyyy date of 10/01/2019? What if the format string conflicts with another type? After all, you can implement `IFormattable` on an object, so you could have `"t"` defined for multiple types.

Comment: ...What if the format string conflicts with another type... -> right didn't thought about these situations.